# Rails 3 routing: include flash params with root redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, routes

In Rails 3 you can set up your root path to redirect elsewhere right from config/routes.rb:

```
root :to => redirect("/dashboard")
```

This works, except that it wipes out any flash params passed to root. How can you pass them along through the redirect?

**Update:** [James Chen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9308472/414220), i.e. rewriting the route declaration as `root :to => redirect { |p, req| req.flash.keep; "/dashboard" }`, works for me. But there are two things I don't understand about it:

1. What does `p` stand for, params?
2. I tried rewriting the block with `do`/`end` and linebreaks:

   ```
   root :to => redirect do |p, req|
     req.flash.keep
     "/dashboard"
   end
   ```

   But this fails with "ArgumentError: redirection argument not supported". Why is this?

Comment: 1. Yes, p stands for params. 2. this is interesting. Seems we have an order issue here. If we put `()` around the `redirect do` block then it works. I always use `{}` since if the block is too complicated it's indicating we should probably write a class for that.

Comment: About 2, It's not the same using curly braces as using do/end for defining blocks. Ruby iterprets as follows: `root(:to => redirect) do # block passed to #root -parentheses can be obviated-` While using curly braces `root :to => redirect{ #block passed to #redirect }`

Comment: @Macario are you saying that without parentheses, Ruby interprets the block as being passed to `root` rather than to `redirect`?

Comment: With or without parentheses is the same, in this case using a do/end block passes the block to root, while using a curly braces block passes it to #redirect wich is to be intended. Here's somewhere where Ruby's syntax can bite.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `flash.keep`.

Write a proc for the redirect in your routes file:

```
root :to => redirect { |p, req| req.flash.keep; "/dashboard" }
```

So flash params from normal redirect to root url will be passed:

```
redirect_to root_url, :notice => "test flash notice"
```

Comment: Updated the OP with a follow up to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

why wouldnt you just do something like

```
root :to => 'dashboard#index'
```

assuming that '/dashboard' leads to the dashboard controller index action.

**Update**

I mean if you reallllly wanted to you could add to the html.erb page that is displayed at '/dashboard'

and do something like this

```
<% if request.referer.scan('yoursitename').size == 0 %>
 <%= create your own notice here %>
<% end %>
```

Edit again... sigh..

Forgot, you could just root `:to => 'whateveryouroriginal#rootareawas'`
then just do:

```
redirect_to '/dashboard'
```

in your whateveryouroriginal controller rootareawas action

This is really dirty but its 2am and i have to drive to Georgia from Illinois.

Hope this helps